# Rails 3 + Exception Notifier gem: How to set up Exception Notifier site-wide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading a project from Rails 2 to Rails 3. It used to send exception emails for every exception that happened in the site, and I want to implement that functionality into the Rails 3 version too. Does anyone know how I would do a site-wide `rescue` so that on any errors/exceptions an email is sent?

Would I do this somewhere in the application controller?

In Rails 2 this can be accomplished like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ExceptionNotification::Notifiable
  ...
end
```

However, I don't see any documentation for that in the Rails 3 gem version so I don't know if it's possible

**ANSWER**

I eventually realized that I did this for another project, and that by default the Rails 3 exception notifier gem provides the above functionality without any need to include any modules. You just have to set up the middleware config and everything happens magically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert but maybe this?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue_not_found
  # HERE YOU HAVE OTHER EXCEPTIONS YOU WANT TO HANDLE

  protected
  def rescue_not_found
     # YOUR CODE HERE
  end
end
```

In this [image](http://rubylearning.com/images/exception.jpg) from this [page](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) you have a list of exceptions.

Comment: Yeh I saw that here http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/basic-exception-notification-in-rails-3/ . Could you briefly explain what `rescue_from` does by default?

Comment: well, `rescue_from` will rescue exceptions raised only in your controllers actions. Any exception that happens will be treated by the method you've defined with `:with` and you can create a method to send the email based on each method, with a specific message. Is that what you were asking about `rescue_from`? :)

Comment: Thanks @Gerep, I eventually realized that I did this for another project, and that by default the Rails 3 exception notifier gem provides the above functionality without any need to include any modules. You just have to set up the middleware config and everything happens magically